# React Native - Global BackHandler behavior depends on registration timing

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm migrating an old React Native app from 0.57 to 0.62, and just setup navigation with the current React Navigation package. That app contains a global navigation store that registers to Android back button presses and allows me to intercept back operations, no matter where they originate (hardware button or programmatically).

I have a rather weird behavior here, and it seems to be timing-related. In the snippet below, I register a listener with `BackHandler`, which supresses back button taps and logs a warning. I'll register it in the `componentDidMount` method.

```
export class RootComponent extends React.Component {   

    private initBackButton() {
        const onBackPress = () => {
            console.warn("BACK BUTTON SUPPRESSED");
            return true;
        };

        BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", onBackPress);
    }


    public componentDidMount() {
        // TODO register back listener
    }


    public render() {
        return (
                <NavigationContainer >
                    <StackNavigatorSetup />
                </NavigationContainer>
        );
    }
}
```

- If I register the listener synchronously, the back button listener fires ***if*** I press it at the initial screen of my `StackNavigator`.
- If I navigate to a second screen, the listener does not fire if I press the back button, and I can return back to the start screen. If I press back there again, the listener fires.
- Note that I'm declaring the listener in the root component, so that component isn't going anywhere.

  ```
  public componentDidMount() {
      // only works on the start screen
      this.initBackButton();
  }
  ```

Now, the behavior is different if I use a delay:

- If I register the same handler with a delay of 1 second, the handler works on any screen
- This is *not* thread-related. If I use a delay that is too short, it again only works on the start screen

  ```
  public componentDidMount() {
      // works on every screen i'll navigate to
      PromiseUtil.delay(1000).then(() => this.initBackButton());
  }
  ```

To be honest, I don't really have a clue what's happening here. `BackHandler` seems to be ready, but I don't understand why the listener works either global or not depending on the delay. Also, my root component doesn't really change, so I wonder whether `React Navigation` is messing with me here...